# Socket Constant Streaming Data

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, networkstream

I have a server application but am getting some intermittent timeouts. I want to start writing back to the client immediately and then defer the rest of my write until my payload is ready. However, nothing I've seen in TcpClient or NetworkStream supports active streaming. In my own test bed, any write to the stream is in isolation, even the Begin/End methods.

For example, in my client side write/read loop, the following server code only sends back a single time entry instead of two.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var listener = TcpListener.Create(2345);

        listener.Start();

        while (true)
        {
            var client = listener.AcceptTcpClientAsync().Result;

            ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(async state =>
            {
                try
                {
                    await HandleClient(state);
                }
                catch (SocketException error) when (error.Message.Contains("existing connection was forcibly closed"))
                {
                    // do nothing
                }
            }, client);
        }
    }

    private static async Task HandleClient(object state)
    {
        var client = (TcpClient) state;
        var stream = client.GetStream();

        while (true)
        {
            var readBuffer = new byte[4096];

            var requestSize = await stream.ReadAsync(readBuffer, 0, readBuffer.Length);

            var requestString = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(readBuffer, 0, requestSize);

            Console.WriteLine($"[{DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString()}] Received: {requestString}");

            if (requestString == "quit")
            {
                break;
            }

            var responseString = DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString();

            var writeBuffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(responseString);

            stream.BeginWrite(writeBuffer, 0, writeBuffer.Length, DelayedWriteCallback, stream);
        }

        client.Close();
        client.Dispose();
    }

    private static void DelayedWriteCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        var stream = (NetworkStream) ar.AsyncState;

        Thread.Sleep(5000);

        var writeString = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString());

        stream.Write(writeString, 0, writeString.Length);
        stream.Flush();

        stream.EndWrite(ar);
    }
```

How do I do this?

Comment: You call another BeginWrite inside your DelayedWriteCallback, after the EndWrite, and add some logic to end the sending. Probably easier to use Tasks, you avoid the callback hassle.

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work. On the client end, the read is completed and the extra writes on the server end don't get returned until more reads are done. I want the client to be hung on the same read until I'm done writing so it all looks like one request/response to the client.

Comment: You use the same logic on both sides (keeping the sockets for the duration), with logic to detect when the whole thing ended. Sockets will just shuffle bytes, as long as you want. The meaning of the data is up to your apps.

Comment: I could, but I don't control the client side.

Comment: Well, if the client won´t accept the "streaming" of data, nothing you can do, right? To me it seems your project istarted at wrong end: a client can only be developed to an existing server or service, no? Also, a client doing an infinite read is of little use (unless it´s just reading a file), it needs to read the data in chunks and decide what to do with it.

Comment: Of course there are things I can do. I simply don't know which object or socket configuration I need to make it work in .NET which is why I'm here.

Comment: _"I want to start writing back to the client immediately and then defer the rest of my write until my payload is ready"_ -- great. You should be able to do that, no problem. _"nothing I've seen in TcpClient or NetworkStream supports active streaming"_ -- please define "active streaming". There is not a single streaming API that exists anywhere that, at some fundamental level, does not involve repeatedly obtaining data from somewhere and writing it to the stream. What is this "active streaming" of which you speak and which you seem to think is somehow different from this.

Comment: All the methods that I've ran across take a set-in-stone byte[]. There is no facility I've seen that supports a more flexible collection such as a Queue or some way to keep the socket open in a writing state so that multiple calls to Write appear to the client as just one long read. In my testing the client still sees periods of no data being available and stops receiving data which means extra Writes on the server simply get buffered for the next read. However, your condescension is noted.

Answer (score 1):

TCP is a streaming protocol, which just means that it will transport any data you send through it and make sure it is received in the correct order on the other side.

That data might be a constant series of bytes, or many seconds of nothing followed by a single byte. TCP does not care, it´s just the pipe for.

This is made clear by the fact that every socket Send and Receive method takes a buffer with a specific size as a parameter (same goes for NetworkStream). The "streaming" of useful data is up to the application, as is the reception and interpretation of the data.

If you want to send data continuously, you need a send() loop that will pump bytes into the socket as soon as your server has them. If you need to read data continuously, you need a loop that will receive() chunks of bytes continuously and make sense of them.